# wait to trigger action

Tags: android, loops, button, while-loop

I am looking to trigger a while loop, but only after the user selects an option.  For some reason now, it is automatically blowing through the entire block of code even before the user picks an option.  How can I force it to wait to continue until a user selects something?

```
case R.id.buttonSetPlayers:
        //**********************//
        //***SET PLAYER COUNT***//
        //**********************//
        AlertDialog.Builder builderPC = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final CharSequence[] playerCount = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
        builderPC.setTitle("Player Count");
        builderPC.setItems(playerCount, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), playerCount[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (playerCount[item].equals("1")){
                    EntryScreen.this.totalPlayerCount = 1;

                }
                else if (playerCount[item].equals("2")){
                    EntryScreen.this.totalPlayerCount = 2;

                }
                else if (playerCount[item].equals("3")){
                    EntryScreen.this.totalPlayerCount = 3;

                }
                else if (playerCount[item].equals("4")){
                    EntryScreen.this.totalPlayerCount = 4;

                }
                return;
            }
        });
        builderPC.create().show();


###

I want it to wait to do this next part instead of doing it as soon as button is clicked.  Below...

###
        while (totalPlayerCount >= 1){
            setNames();
            totalPlayerCount--;
        }

        return;
```

Comment: I find the question a bit unclear, were you waiting for `builderPC.create().show();` to block?

Comment: Sorry, the while loop just below my comment... is what i dont want to trigger until the user has selected 1-4.  Then i need that process to loop that many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the while loop in onClick or a method called by onClick. `builderPC.create().show();` does not block or do anything to wait for the response but onclick is trigged by the user response. Just remember this will run on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you... Not sure why I did not think about this before.  I just create a while loop inside setNames() and then triggered that in each of the if statements, so once selected it would run through setNames a set amount of times.