# Combined String not attaching to value

Tags: java, android, database, string, null

Is anyone able to see why my string with a made up name is not attaching itself to a value?

```
public void setNames() {

    //*******************//
    //***DATABASE INFO***//
    //*******************//
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    if (totalPlayerCount >= 1){  


    //**********************//
    //***SET PLAYER NAMES***//
    //**********************//
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Player " + nameLoop);
    alert.setMessage("Name:");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      String newName = "name"+nameLoop;
      // If i put "name1" here like so, the value "wow" stays with "name1" all the way to the database and does not end up null
      name1 = "wow";
      newName = input.getText().toString(); <-- newName should be name1, name2, name3, name4 each time around.  If i do a simple Toast, it displays name1, name2, etc.  But when i insert those values into the database, they are all null.
      setNames();
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();

    nameLoop++;

    }
    if (totalPlayerCount == 0){
        db.open();
        db.insertPlayers(String.valueOf(name1), String.valueOf(name2), String.valueOf(name3),
                String.valueOf(name4));
        db.close();

        AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //myAlertDialog.setTitle("Saved");
        myAlertDialog.setMessage("Names saved");
        myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                return;
            } }); 
        myAlertDialog.show();
    }   
    totalPlayerCount--;
    return;
}
```

Here is the same clip just broken out that I am having trouble with

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      String newName = "name"+nameLoop;
      // If i put "name1" here like so, the value "wow" stays with "name1" all the way to the database and does not end up null
      name1 = "wow";
      newName = input.getText().toString(); <-- newName should be name1, name2, name3, name4 each time around.  If i do a simple Toast, it displays name1, name2, etc.  But when i insert those values into the database, they are all null.
      setNames();
      }
    });
```

Comment: When you call insertPlayers(...) Calling String.valueOf(String) is just creates overhead and no useful work gets done. Where is name1 declared?

Comment: name1-4 are all declared public Strings at the very beginning of the class.. i think I may see whats wrong but not sure how to get around it.

i set newName = "name"+nameLoop; which becomes name1

but right after that, newName = input.getText().toString();

which means newName is no longer name1.

Comment: i think i need to create an array or something?? name[] or something like that?? not sure, but i need name to change from name1 to name2 each time through.

Comment: i don't get where you are setting the values for name2 name3 etc.. if you want to insert each name entered by the user into the database.. just declare a string list and add the name to the list and then iterate it and insert into database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically create a variable and then assign it a value. Java does not work like javascript.

You have to replace your

```
  String newName = "name"+nameLoop;
  // If i put "name1" here like so, the value "wow" stays with "name1" all the way to the database and does not end up null
  name1 = "wow";
  newName = input.getText().toString(); <-- newName should be name1, name2, name3, name4 each time around.  If i do a simple Toast, it displays name1, name2, etc.  But when i insert those values into the database, they are all null.
```

section with a switch statement.

```
String newName = input.getText().toString();
switch(nameLoop){
case 1: name1=newName;break;
case 2: name2=newName;break;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The short version alert.show() does not block so you're executing the database insert before you're getting the name1 value assignment back via onClick.

The Long version, take a few steps back and learn some of Java's syntax and how event based programming works. This is the [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879656/wait-to-trigger-action) like this today. It is a great thing that you're eager to work but I reccommend you focus on some of the basics before you start running ahead full steam. With a good understanding you'll be able to code father and faster with less stress and fewer detours. `an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure`